# Validating JTW token generated by Azured AD B2C

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to implement Azure AD B2C auth on my endpoints using Azure Functions.

When I call  https://{MyAzureAd}.b2clogin.com/{MyAzureAd}.onmicrosoft.com/{Flow}/oauth2/v2.0/token

I got this result...

```
{
  "access_token": "...",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "refresh_token": "..."
}
```

The access token is a JWT.... Now I need to checjk if the token is really valid, but I don't know how or where the secret is located....

I gone already to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenantId%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration) and got the x5c to use as certificate, but it's not working...Any clue ? this is my code...

```
    if (!req.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Authorization hader");
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            string authorizationHeader = req.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Authorization is null");
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            IDictionary<string, object> claims = null;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(authorizationHeader);
                if (authorizationHeader.StartsWith("Bearer"))
                {
                    authorizationHeader = authorizationHeader.Substring(7);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(authorizationHeader);

                // Validate the token and decode the claims.
                claims = new JwtBuilder()
                    .WithAlgorithm(new HMACSHA256Algorithm())
                    .WithSecret("Where on Azure Portal can I get this ????")
                    .MustVerifySignature()
                    .Decode<IDictionary<string, object>>(authorizationHeader);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
            string Username = Convert.ToString(claims["username"]);
            string Role = Convert.ToString(claims["role"]);
            Console.WriteLine(Username, Role);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your title you ask for "Decoding", but in your post you ask for "Validating" a token.

For decoding you only need base64 with some char replacements, you can even do that on frontend without a problem:

```js
const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
const decodedToken = JSON.parse(atob(base64));
```

For validation, aspnet has inbuildt middleware that handles it for you:

```cs
// in ConfigureServices
services.AddAuthentication(o => o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Authority = Configuration["B2cAuthority"];
    o.Audience = Configuration["B2cAudience"];
});

// in Configure

app.UseAuthentication();
```

In Azure Functions you can use it almost identically as outlined here: https://blog.darkloop.com/post/bringing-authorizeattribute-to-net-azure-functions-v2

Comment: Thanks, Markus..And you are right...poor title....I fixed ! However the example that you supplied is not so good and may not be a goof fit for Azure AD B2C in particular...but thanks ! (And yes...I need something for Azure Functions)

Comment: actually that's exactly how to implement azure b2c. after the middleware you can use the "User" idnetity in HttpContext (you can access HttpContext in the HttpRequest parameter when using azure functions).